# Akka scheduler stops on exception; is it expected?

Tags: scala, akka

We run this code:

```
scheduler.schedule(1 minute, 1 minute) { triggerOperations.tick() }
```

when starting our application, where scheduler is an Akka actorSystem.scheduler.
If tick() throws an exception, then it is never called again!

I checked the documentation, but cannot find any statement that this is expected.  Mostly the description is "Schedules a function to be run repeatedly with an initial delay and a frequency", with no mention that if the function throws an excpetion the task will stop firing.

Our akka version is 2.3.2.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/scheduler.html
http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/Scheduler.html

Is this behavior expected?  Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It's as Tim explains below, it won't be re-scheduled by design. Thanks for pointing that out - we'll improve the docs to explain this: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18346

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in doubt, go to source. The code is a bit terse, but [this](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/be3b9ea2b78c65036036c0489b7223ded802d20a/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala#L101) fragment:

```
 override def run(): Unit = {
   try {
     runnable.run()
     val driftNanos = clock() - getAndAdd(delay.toNanos)
     if (self.get != null)
       swap(schedule(executor, this, Duration.fromNanos(Math.max(delay.toNanos - driftNanos, 1))))
   } catch {
      case _: SchedulerException ⇒ // ignore failure to enqueue or terminated target actor
   }
```

}

shows that if your runnable throws, scheduler does not reschedule the next execution (which happens inside swap as far as I understand).

Comment: Thanks!  I was so surprised by the behavior being different from the documentation that I thought I must have misunderstood something.  It's especially confounding because it's an "exceptional" case, so it was not discovered during testing.  Glad to see they are going to update the docs.

Comment: Incidentally, the source doesn't tell me if it was by design or not, i.e. is it a bug or a feature :)